# save object in db as-is or as json?

Tags: java, mysql, serialization

I have an object that its content I want to save in mysql. What I'm doing now is convert it to JSON and write it as text. If I need to read it I decode the json and create the same object. But I saw that I can save the object to mysql db as Object and read it as object, then cast it to my class. I do not need to have the ability to search in the json.

lets say this is my object:

```
class bus extends car{
  private int seats;
  private Person driver;

  public bus(Person driver){
    super();
    this.seats = 50;
    this.driver = driver;
  }
}
```

So what is the preferred way(time, coding, memory usage etc..)?
And what is the correct way to save this kind of object in mysql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than saving it as JSON you could use xstream and serialize your class to xml, which can then be saved as 'clob' to the database. Once you deserialize using xstream it will give back the object so you don't have to do manual conversion. xstream also supports serializing to json as well.

http://x-stream.github.io/

http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Comment: there isnt `CLOB` in mysql, only `TEXT` or `BLOB`. can you add an example on working with db, i managed to save it but when i get the xml back i cant cast it to the original object..

Comment: @nir did u deserialize the contents using xstream ?

Comment: i manage to fix it (problem in my code). however the insert got to 2mb size with pretty lean object. this seems too much.

Comment: What are your mysql space declarations?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need options provided by this format than consider to use standard way - binary format based on serialization

There are benefits

1. Very less space consuming
2. No need third party libs
3. Out of box solution, because of java

Consider to use special ORM tools for this reason. It will dramatically simplify your task and save your time.

There are ORM tools
1. Hibernate
2. MyBatis
3. Eclipse link
4. Spring jdbc

Using one of them let you concentrate on a business points rather than on a low level concepts